# Injection of autowired dependencies failed with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make a simple application with SPing but I keep getting this error and I dont understand why.

I have tried everything, even wre-wrote the whole app. Dont even know what the problem could be.

This is the error I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogPostController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vst.blog.service.BlogService com.vst.blog.controller.BlogPostController.blogServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vst.blog.service.BlogService com.vst.blog.controller.BlogPostController.blogServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 24 more

Jul 14, 2020 9:46:20 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogPostController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vst.blog.service.BlogService com.vst.blog.controller.BlogPostController.blogServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vst.blog.service.BlogService com.vst.blog.controller.BlogPostController.blogServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 24 more

Jul 14, 2020 9:46:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogPostController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vst.blog.service.BlogService com.vst.blog.controller.BlogPostController.blogServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vst.blog.service.BlogService com.vst.blog.controller.BlogPostController.blogServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vst.blog.service.BlogService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 24 more
```

Here is the class that's giving issues(BlogPostController)

```
package com.vst.blog.controller;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.vst.blog.model.BlogPost;
import com.vst.blog.service.BlogService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
public class BlogPostControllerImpl {
    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(BlogPostControllerImpl.class);   
    
    @Autowired
    BlogService blogServiceImpl;
    
    BlogPostControllerImpl(){}
    
    @RequestMapping(value= "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/web-inf/pages/index.jsp");
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadPosts")
    public ModelAndView listPosts(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<BlogPost> listPosts = blogServiceImpl.selectBlogPostS();
        model.addObject("listPosts", listPosts);
        model.setViewName("post");
        return model;   
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newPost", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newPost(ModelAndView model) {
        BlogPost post = new BlogPost();
        model.addObject("post", post);
        model.setViewName("post_form");
        return model;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/savePost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView savePost(@ModelAttribute BlogPost post) throws SQLException {
        if (post.getBlog_id() == 0) { 
            blogServiceImpl.insertBlogPost(post);
        } else {
            blogServiceImpl.updateBlogPost(post);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/loadAlbums");
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/editPost", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editPost(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int postId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("blog_id"));
        BlogPost post = blogServiceImpl.selectBlogPostById(postId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("post_form");
        model.addObject("post", post);
        return model;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deletePost", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deletePost(HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        int postId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("blog_id"));
        blogServiceImpl.deleteBlogPost(postId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/loadPosts");
    }

}
```

This is the class interface.

```
package com.vst.blog.service;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.vst.blog.model.BlogPost;

public interface BlogService {

    public void insertBlogPost(BlogPost post) throws SQLException;

    public BlogPost selectBlogPostById(int id);

    public List<BlogPost> selectBlogPostS();

    public void deleteBlogPost(int id) throws SQLException;
    
    public void updateBlogPost(BlogPost post) throws SQLException;
}
```

And here is the implementation of it:

```
package com.vst.blog.service;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.vst.blog.dao.BlogPostDao;
import com.vst.blog.dao.BlogPostDaoImpl;
import com.vst.blog.dao.BlogPostDaoImpl;
import com.vst.blog.model.BlogPost;

@Service
@Transactional
public class BlogServiceImpl implements BlogService {
    
    @Autowired
    private BlogPostDao postDao;
    
    public BlogServiceImpl () {
        //postDao = new BlogPostDaoImpl();
    }


    public void insertBlogPost(BlogPost post) throws SQLException {
        postDao.insertBlogPost(post);
    }

    public BlogPost selectBlogPostById(int id) {
        return postDao.selectBlogPostById(id);
    }

    public List<BlogPost> selectBlogPostS() {
        return postDao.selectBlogPostS();
    }


    public void deleteBlogPost(int id) throws SQLException {
        postDao.deleteBlogPost(id);
    }

    public void updateBlogPost(BlogPost post) throws SQLException{
        postDao.updateBlogPost(post);
    }

}
```

This is DaoImpl

```
package com.vst.blog.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.vst.blog.model.BlogPost;

@Service
@Transactional
public class BlogPostDaoImpl implements BlogPostDao {
    
    public BlogPostDaoImpl () {}

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    public void insertBlogPost(BlogPost post) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(post);

    }

    public BlogPost selectBlogPostById(int id) {
        
        return (BlogPost) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(
                BlogPost.class, id);
        

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<BlogPost> selectBlogPostS() {
        
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from blog")
                .list();

    }


    public void deleteBlogPost(int id)  {
        BlogPost post = (BlogPost) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                BlogPost.class, id);
        if (null != post) {
            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(post);
        }
        

    }


    public BlogPost updateBlogPost(BlogPost post)  {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(post);
        return post;

    }

}
```

And here is its interface

```
package com.vst.blog.dao;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.vst.blog.model.*;

@Repository
public interface BlogPostDao {

    public void insertBlogPost(BlogPost post) throws SQLException;

    public BlogPost selectBlogPostById(int id);

    public List<BlogPost> selectBlogPostS();

    public void deleteBlogPost(int id) throws SQLException;
    
    public BlogPost updateBlogPost(BlogPost post) throws SQLException;
    
}
```

This is spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, 
        DAO -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vst" />



    <!-- Getting Database properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.vst.blog.model"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Missing package declaration information for the java code listed above.

Comment: interface BlogService should not have any class level annotation

Comment: @MillerCyChan I removed the package declarations and imports to shorted the code I pasted here. Do you need to see them? Also, I removed the annotation you mentioned but the error remains.

Comment: what is the package of `BlogServiceImpl` class

Comment: And, please also update your question to reflect your current code, with a hit (:

Comment: @Anas ```BlogServiceImpl``` is a part of ```com.vst.blog.service```. I also updated the post to show the full error and all the package names.

Comment: but your controller declaration is `BlogPostControllerImpl` while the error log talk about `BlogPostController`?

Comment: Thats strange. I dont even have a class/interface called BlogPostController. I will investigate where this comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some tips to detect this rare errors related to:

**Injection of autowired dependencies failed**

- Use just one scan:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.VST" />
```

Instead

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.VST.blog.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.VST.blog.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.VST.blog.dao" />
```

- validate that all your spring beans are in this package or child of it:

  `com.VST`
- create an empty class with some method inside of your base package com.vst and try to autowire it. This could reveal that not even a simple empty autowire works!!
- Remove "impl"  from autowired clases. In your example, change this

```
BlogService blogServiceImpl;
```

to

```
BlogService blogService;
```

in your BlogPostControllerImpl

---

## Another tips

- don't use uppercase in packages
- use spring boot :D

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I implemented them but the error persists.

Comment: Some times it is not possible to autowire some bean because it has errors. Do you have more log?

Comment: I added the entire log output.

Comment: I liked the comment "Use SpringBoot". :D

Comment: #1 just to test, could you create an empty class with some method inside of your base package **com.vst** and try to autowire it?  #2 spring boot is awesome! #3 change this BlogService blogServiceImpl; to BlogService blogService; in your **BlogPostControllerImpl**

Comment: @JRichardsz I renamed it to BlogPostController and it seems to have fixed the issue. Now all I see is some error of no mapping found. Thanks a lot though! Update your answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Interesting... maybe your ide is "crazy", but simulating new autowires or rename them, could helps!

Comment: updated!! and also, if you publish a minimal expression of your code in github, maybe I can show you how migrate it to spring-boot.. cc @KunalVohra